# Parsing XML file to custom class - InvalidCastException

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, exception

I have a custom XML file that looks like this with some 'n' entries in it..I am trying to load all the values onto the lst variable and do a foreach loop on it for further processing...

```xml
  <ItemInfo>
    <StartTime>2014-06-16T00:00:00</StartTime>
    <EndTime>2014-06-16T23:59:59</EndTime>
    <Text>Calendar Project Started</Text>
    <A>255</A>
    <R>255</R>
    <G>0</G>
    <B>0</B>
  </ItemInfo>
  <ItemInfo>
    <StartTime>2014-08-02T00:00:00</StartTime>
    <EndTime>2014-08-02T23:59:59</EndTime>
    <Text>First Release</Text>
    <A>255</A>
    <R>255</R>
    <G>0</G>
    <B>0</B>
  </ItemInfo>
```

I am trying to parse them using the `Deserialze()` method.

```vb
 Private Sub Form4_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim fi As System.IO.FileInfo = New IO.FileInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "items.xml"))
        If fi.Exists Then
            Dim lst As New List(Of ItemInfo)
            Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(ItemInfo))
            Dim fs As New IO.FileStream("items.xml", IO.FileMode.Open)
            Dim reader As System.Xml.XmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(fs)          
            lst = CTypeDynamic(serializer.Deserialize(reader), lst.GetType)  '->Invalid cast Exception
            fs.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

The custom class is as follows:

```vb
Public Class ItemInfo
    Public StartTime As DateTime
    Public EndTime As DateTime
    Public Text As String
    Public A As Int32
    Public R As Int32
    Public G As Int32
    Public B As Int32
    Dim pattern As HatchStyle
    Dim patternColor As Color

    Public Sub ItemInfo(startTime As DateTime, endTime As DateTime, text As String, color As Color)
        startTime = startTime
        endTime = endTime
        text = text
        A = color.A
        R = color.R
        G = color.G
        B = color.B
    End Sub
End Class
```

The exception message is:

> Conversion from type 'ItemInfo' to type 'List(Of ItemInfo)' is not valid.

Any pointers as to where I am doing a mistake?

Comment: Your XML is invalid (it misses a root node).

Comment: I removed the first line from the XML file as I got an exception for that as 
`Additional information: <ArrayOfItemInfo xmlns=''> was not expected.` 
The root node was 
`<ArrayOfItemInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">`

And I am still facing the same problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the wrong type to initialize the `XmlSerializer`.

Your XML contains an array of items, and you try to deserialize it into a `List(Of ItemInfo)`, so you should use:

```
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(lst.GetType())
```

instead of

```
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(ItemInfo))
```

to deserialize into a `List(Of ItemInfo)`, not a single `ItemInfo`.

Comment: awesome...that worked like a charm..... I guess when we watch a code too close we miss out important details :)  Thanks a tonne @sloth :)